# Object Required Error - Populate PPT from Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

```
Sub SendToPPT()

Dim ppt As Object
Set ppt = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

ppt.Presentations.Open ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & "Allegation.pptx"

For i = 6 To 24
ppt.Slides(i).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text
Next i

ppt.Save
ppt.Close
Set ppt = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm receiving a

> Run time Error 424: Object Required.

I'm unable to figure out where I'm going wrong. The file path is correct, I've cross-checked it.

Comment: ActivePresentation is a PowerPoint object so needs qualifying otherwise VBA will assume you are referring to an object in the host object model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ppt` is the `"Powerpoint.Application"` but `ppt.Slides(i)` expects a presentation not the powerpoint application.

```
Dim Pres As Object
Set Pres = ppt.Presentations.Open(ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & "Allegation.pptx")

Dim i As Long
For i = 6 To 24
    Pres.Slides(i).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text
Next i

Pres.Save
Pres.Close
Set Pres = Nothing
Set ppt = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand the error now. I'm still receiving the same [error message](https://i.imgur.com/cvq7BlQ.png), unfortunately. How can I debug and troubleshoot this?

Comment: @BhaveshShaha Try changing `ActivePresentation` into `ppt.ActivePresentation`

Comment: Got the error! While my file path was "right", executing the macro on Word required me to use `ActiveDocument` instead. Thank you!